# How to access Cloud Firestore from Google Sheets?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access Cloud Firestore database from Google sheet with the help of [FirestoreGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) example, but as explained in the 5th point I have downloaded the file but not getting where to update the `client_email`, `private_key` and `project_id` in the project.
So kindly guide me to move forward.

*When you press "Create," your browser will download a `.json` file with your private key (`private_key`), service account email (`client_email`), and project ID (`project_id`). Copy these values into your Google Apps Script — you'll need them to authenticate with Firestore.*

with a demo
Code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
  projectid: "xxx";
  key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPrivateKeyHere\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  email: "xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
  
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
}
```

error

```
ReferenceError: "email" is not defined. (line 7, file "Code")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do as follows, for example in a simple function that fetches a collection:

```
function fecthFirstCollectionDocs() {

  var email = "xxxxxx@yyyyyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
  var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\your key here\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var projectId = "zzzzzzzzz";

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);

  const allDocuments = firestore.query("FirstCollection").execute();
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(allDocuments));

}
```

The value of `key` is obtained by creating a service account, as explained in the Library documentation: https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#creating-a-service-account. It's quite easy, just follow the instructions.

You have to copy only the part between `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n` from the `.json` file.

---

Edited following you comment of 9 April:

To solve the

```
ReferenceError: "email" is not defined. (line 7, file "Code")
```

error you should correctly declare the variables you pass to the `getFirestore()` method, as shown in the code of my answer, and as follows:

instead of doing

```
  projectid: "fir-79c39";
```

you should do

```
  var projectid = "fir-79c39";
```

You declare a variable named `projectid` that you use in the `getFirestore()` method. The same for `key` and `email`.

Comment: I have tried updating the above credentials in the `Firestore.gs` file but it throws an error `Invalid argument: key (line 57, file "Authenticate")` so can you tell in which file do I need to update it.

Comment: Just do a test in the default .gs file, i.e. in the one you see when you do Tools > Script editor. After that you can make it more complex with several files, if needed.

Comment: I have added in the question error I am facing in demo test

Comment: You should do var email = xxxx it is similar to JavaScript.

Comment: @TusharRai Did you succeed in implementing the example?

Comment: Yes finally I acheived the authentication and writing data to firestore. thank you @Renaud

Comment: @TusharRai: What did you have to do to get it working? Please consider answering this SO question... https://stackoverflow.com/q/58568467

Answer (score 2):

```
function writeDataToFirestore() {
  var projectId = "XXXXXXXX";
  var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var email = "firestoredart2demo@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  const data = {
    "name": "test!"
  }
  firestore.createDocument("FirstCollection", data)
}
```