# How to write data to Firebase Cloud Firestore using Google Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to write test data to my Firebase Cloud Firestore. After running my script `writeDataToFirestore()`, I expect to see a successful execution of my GAS and the test data in my firestore. But, instead, I get the following error.

> Execution failed: Invalid argument: key (line 57, file "Authenticate", project "FirestoreApp")

I followed the instructions on all the [documentation here](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#creating-a-service-account) to get my `client_email`, `private_key` and `project_id` from the Cloud Platform.

Code.gs

```js
function writeDataToFirestore() {
  // library: 1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw

  var email = my.client_email;
  var key = my.private_key;
  var projectId = my.project_id;

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);

  const data = {
    "name": "test!"
  };

  firestore.createDocument("FirstCollection", data);
}
```

Here is the entire execution transcript.

> Execution Transcript
>   
> [19-10-25 15:45:32:675 PDT] Starting execution
>   
> [19-10-25 15:45:32:719 PDT] Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe([{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}]) [0 seconds]
>   
> [19-10-25 15:45:32:719 PDT] Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe([{"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore","aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","exp":1572047132.691,"iat":1572043532.691}]) [0 seconds]
>   
> [19-10-25 15:45:32:723 PDT] Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature([eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvZGF0YXN0b3JlIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9vYXV0aDIuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE1NzIwNDcxMzIuNjkxLCJpYX...) [0.003 seconds]
>   
> [19-10-25 15:45:32:732 PDT] Execution failed: Invalid argument: key (line 57, file "Authenticate", project "FirestoreApp") [0.033 seconds total runtime]

Comment: **getFirestore(email, key, projectId)** - you have to substitute the email, key and projectUId that you got when you registered your Firestore project. [Now, with **YOUR** service account client email address email, private key key, and project ID projectId,](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#creating-a-service-account)

Comment: @Tedinoz: Thanks, but I did that already. By following the instructions on the documentation we both linked to.

Comment: Which line is #57?

Comment: @Tedinoz: I'm pretty sure "line 57" does not refer to my code. But instead, it refers to a line inside the FirestoreApp library.

Comment: I think that from your error message, `key` of `var key = my.private_key;` is not correct. So how about generating new private key at "Service account" of "Settings" of project of Firebase? BY this, new JSON file can be downloaded. Then, please use the private key from it. If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: Is a paid account (either at Firebase (Cloud Firestore) or Google (Cloud Platform)) necessary to access this functionality? Or can I write to Cloud Firestore using all free accounts?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When my comment had not resolved your issue, I have to apologize. By the way, about your new question, you can see about the cost at [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=en). Please check this for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike: Please consider helping answering this question... https://stackoverflow.com/q/58568467/1640892

Comment: Although I commented to your new question, I think that that might should be added to this question.

Comment: Have you read [How to access Cloud Firestore from Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55472053/1330560)? Your question looks like a duplicate.