# Which part of the private key for service accounts in Google Cloud Platform do I actually use?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to verify I have the `private_key` correct as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566667/how-to-write-data-to-firebase-cloud-firestore-using-google-apps-script?noredirect=1#comment103453196_58566667).

[Docs about service account private keys are here.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)

```
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "[PROJECT-ID]",
"private_key_id": "[KEY-ID]",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "[SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL]",
"client_id": "[CLIENT-ID]",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/[SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL]"
}
```

When using `private_key`, do I just get the part in between the

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

string and the

```
\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

In other words, the `[PRIVATE-KEY]` shown in the example?

Or do I get the entire string including the two "bookend" strings shown above?

Also, within the `[PRIVATE-KEY]` string, there are several occurrences of the `\n` substring. Do I remove them or leave them in?

Comment: The private key is `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"` as shown in the JSON file. So please use `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"` as `key` of `var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);`. But I thought that posting this question might have tried both `[PRIVATE-KEY]` and `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`. If it's so, can you explain the method for retrieving the JSON file?

Comment: @Tanaike: Yes, I tested every possible option. I will detail and double check my method for retrieving the JSON file. But in the meantime, please note that in this SO answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472398... they said "You have to copy only the part between `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n` from the .json file." Are they wrong?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the thread, the private key is `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"` as shown in the JSON file. If `[PRIVATE-KEY]` is used for [the library](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) as the private key, an error occurs. When you tested `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"` as the private key, an error occurs, I think that the method for retrieving  JSON file might have an issue.

Comment: I do not htink they are wrong, as the FirestoreGoogleAppsScript eventually passes the key to [this function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeRsaSha256Signature(String,String)) which uses the entire block, including the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` boilerplate.

Comment: Rewrite your question to show how you want to use the Private Key. Private Keys have several different formats. The "bookends" tell the application (library) what format the private key is in. The "bookends" are required. The format that you are showing is for "human reading" and requires processing to be used by most APIs. Notice the "\n" in the string. This is not part of the Private Key and is used for display formatting. Software normally will remove the "\n" called newlines and base64 decode the string back to a binary key. The actual steps depend on how "smart" the library is.

Comment: If you are curious on how to use a Google Service Account Private Key, I wrote an article with Python to show the use. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: @Tanaike: I got it working. Turns out all your answers were correct. The issue was my method for retrieving JSON had a bug. And the private key is formatted as you described. Nice job and thank you +1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Cloud Firestore from Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472053/how-to-access-cloud-firestore-from-google-sheets)

Answer (score 2):

This question is also related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566667), so look out for similar symptoms when debugging.

## Troubleshooting steps:

1. Verify that the JSON file is the one generated for your service acocunt
2. Verify that the JSON file is being read properly.
3. Verify that you are using the correct Firebase methods

## Conclusion:

This issue with Firebase authentication was caused by a malfunctioning JSON reading.

It's important to note that the private keys are **meant to be used** with the "useless" information, since the [method to decode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeRsaSha256Signature(String,String)) the private key is expecting those strings to be there.

## TL;DR

The problem was reading the JSON file correctly.

Thanks to [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) and [@Tedinoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330560/tedinoz) for the troubleshooting steps.