# Firebase: sync data in real time from firebase to excel

Tags: excel, database, firebase, synchronization

So I have my firebase database, and in the end of the day it is important for me to see my selled product details in a more readable format. Is it possible to synchronise my firebase with an excel file? for example when i change a value on firebase to instantly see it in my excel document.

Comment: Is it necessary to be excel? There is great Google sheet integration.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore it will be easier for me to be excel, but please tell me more about this google sheet integration

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472053/how-to-access-cloud-firestore-from-google-sheets) shows getting data from firestore.

Comment: do you know if there is any good youtube video for this? i have only found unclear videos

Comment: Youtube isn't a great source for coding help in my opinion. The question I linked has a good answer and links to documentation. You should give it a try first and ask a new question if you run into any problems with the code.